# Is there a way to access or create Excel documents in the Replit Online IDE using Java

Tags: java, excel, replit

I want to implement the Apache Poi Packages into the IDE so that I can manipulate some documents but I am unsure of how to do so

Comment: That is not a task for an online IDE, especially because you are working with documents, which are external files. Get a local IDE.

Comment: Thank you! Anyones that you recommend?